# What are these SR-71 "Ports" for?

Tags: feature-identification, sr-71

In [this video](https://youtu.be/Tnda8IVqkyI?t=165) at the 2:40 minute mark there is a relatively clear image of the rear of a Blackbird.  This is a new view - at least for me. Are those "ports" and, if so, what are they venting?  IF not, what are they?

Here is a snapshot at roughly that time:
[image]

Comment: please update the link.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [SR-71 handbook section 6-11](https://books.google.fi/books?id=GVDZDwAAQBAJ&lpg=SA6-PA3&ots=uj7tMQFY5b&dq=sr-71%20tail%20vents&hl=fi&pg=SA6-PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false), these are fuel dump vents (outer) and fuel tank pressure relief vent (center).

Since this is copyrighted material, I will not include a screenshot of the page, please follow the link above to view the page.

In some models these vents were relocated, because a camera system air conditioning appendage was added to the tail of the plane

Comment: In [action](http://www.habu.org/a-12/06924.html)